# Capybara: get content within the <script> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Using Capybara with Rails, I want to get the content with a `<script>` tag that sits under the `<body>`. When I run this code, the value returned is blank. Is there any way to get the content within the `<script>` tag within the `<body>`?:

```
page.all('body script', visible: false).each do |el|
  puts 'script: '
  puts el.value.to_s
end
```

I've also tried `puts el.text.to_s` also with the same result.

There are a number of script tag elements (which all print as blank in the code above). One example of a script tag:

```
<script>
sConfig.backendTime = 655;
</script>
```

Comment: do you get the output `script: ` then blank, or no output at all?

Comment: Script and then blank

Comment: Please post the script tag as it is in the html

Comment: I posted an update in my question giving an example of script tag as it is shown in the page source. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well your code does better for you than for me.  I can't even get capybara to find the script tag at all. So I won't be much help. Sorry.

Comment: actually I just realised capybara was looking at my login page instead of the page I wanted to test! I've just worked it out. See my answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering why you would like to test something that resides in your <script> tags.. care to eleborate? I'm pretty new to testing and have never tested anything inside <script>. Thanks!

Comment: @bo-oz I'm not using capybara for testing, I'm retrieving data from a particular site where the data is sitting in a json string within a block of javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capybaras #text method takes a parameter to determine whether or not to return hidden text, the following should work with all drivers

```
page.all('body script', visible: false).each do |el|
  puts 'script: '
  puts el.text(:all)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `native` method like this:

```
page.all('body script', visible: false).each do |el|
  puts 'script: '
  puts el.native.text
end
```

Comment: When I run this it returns the text of the body content but not actually any content within the script tag.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the webdriver when it goes into native mode, can i ask what is your webdriver? I am using poltergeist.

Comment: Accessing methods on native should be used as a last resort since it makes code driver dependent. Capybaras #text method can return non-visible text as documented here http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Atext  which should work across all drivers. See my answer below